# CoreImage facedetection method does not work properly in live video

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, image-processing, core-image

I am processing frames from live iPad camera. I am using CoreImage Facedetection method. It works fine on close ups. but when i stand far from the camera so that my whole body is in view. It does not detects the face. Please guide where is the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: I've located the issue] I've located the issue, please don't cover up your eyes and/or mouth.

The iPad's camera has a significantly lower resolution than an iPhone camera, so it would make sense that from farther away the face detection does not work because the resolution isn't high enough, or there could be a minimum size for facial features that hasn't been met, because otherwise the device would pick up faces in all kinds of small objects.